# Difference in Difference Regression (Showing a change in independent variable coefficient for treat-post group)

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference

I want to measure the the change in the relationship between one of my independent variables (gold price) and my dependent (conflict deaths) for my treatment post group. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My hypothesis is that in the treat-post group, the correlation coefficient between gold price and conflict is weaker and I would like to measure this.

Comment: Welcome. Your question needs a little more focus. Are you familiar with this methodology? What have you tried thus far?